# Wordpress woocommerce lightbox popup doesn't work

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, lightbox

I have a woocommerce shop website and in the single product page i have this issue about clicking on the main image. The site redirects me to a page with the image link instead of showing the lightbox.

Comment: Enable lightbox effect on product images on backend Woocommerce -> Settings -> Products -> display
like this url http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wc-settings&tab=products&section=display

Comment: In fact I did that and it was enabled, shown and functional for the gallery pictures. But not the main picture.

Comment: Check the product main picture link have attribute something data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]" or if you are using other plugin for popup effect compare main picture or gallery images tag anchor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is since Woocommerce 3.0, I think they changed the way to zoom image. I fixed the issue by adding `add_theme_support('wc-product-gallery-lightbox')` line in main `functions.php` file of the theme.